# Substitute alt attribute with title attribute using sed

Tags: html, regex, sed, pcre

I have a PCRE regex that looks like this

```
s/(<input.+?)alt(=".+?".*?>)/$1title$2/
```

Can anybody help me with making that work on sed?

Eventually can anybody point me to some guide/blog post/whatever that explains differences between sed regex and PCRE?

Comment: yes :S. It is pure nonsense, that's why i need sed

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something like this:

```
's/\(\<input[^>]\+\?\)alt\(=[^>]\+\?>\)/\1title\2/g'
```

And [this](http://www.cs.utk.edu/~vose/c-stuff/sed_tutorial.html) is a good site for understanding sed.

Comment: Found it! 's/\\(\<input[^[><]]\+\?\\)alt\\(=[^[><]]\+\?>\\)/\1title\2/g'

Comment: The [link you provided](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~vose/c-stuff/sed_tutorial.html) is dead :(